# beginner question on recursion in javascript with BST

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-tree

I am trying to broaden my limited understanding of recursion. I have been working on a Binary Search Tree and am currently attempting to implement a traversal function. I started off with using a Pre-order Traversal, did that no problem and moved on to In-order which seemed much trickier to me. I couldn't figure out a recursive solution on my own so I googled it and found many variations of the same answer-

```
function inOrderHelper(root) {
   if (root !== null) {
      inOrderHelper(root.left);
      console.log(root.data);
      inOrderHelper(root.right);
   }
}
```

Very simple code with even simpler explanations, none of which helped me undestand what exactly this function is doing. So, since you guys have been so helpful previously, I was hoping you could help me expand my knowledge here.

1. How does the program know to stop before the tree is finished? It seems to me that it should continue to go to the runner's left node until it is null, at which point it will skip the console.log
2. How does the program know that a node has already been printed? It seems to me that it would just print the minimum value repeatedly or once before traversing to the maximum value but apparently the nodes are being checked off somehow.
3. How are all the values printed? For example, if the second smallest value is the right node of the third smallest, value, how is the second smallest value account for?

Comment: You might notice from the answers (several of which are very good!) that their examples are not necessary BSTs.  That's because the contents of the tree are not relevant to how inorder traversal works.  Any binary tree can be traversed in an inorder method.  But an inorder traversal is important to BSTs because it is the way to list all the elements in a sorted manner.

Comment: TLDR: This says visit the left node, then print the value at the current node, finally visit the right node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to understand code is usually to try it out with a debugger. Chrome has an [excellent debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference) which you can use to step through the code, line by line, as it runs in real time.

The next easiest way is to use console logs to print out what's happening, which is how most programmers over a certain age would figure out what was happening before debuggers made it easier.

Since I can't sit next to you with a debugger open, let's do the next best thing and add some console logs so we can see what's happening:

```js
function inOrderHelper(root) {
   console.group("Entering inOrderHelper with ", root);
   if (root !== null && root !== undefined) {
      console.log("Root is not null, so continue");

      console.group("Traversing down the left node");
      inOrderHelper(root.left);
      console.groupEnd();

      console.log("The root value is ", root.value);

      console.group("Traversing down the right node");
      inOrderHelper(root.right);
      console.groupEnd();
   } else {
      console.log("Root is null, so back up");
   }
   console.log("Exiting inOrderHelper");
   console.groupEnd();
}
```

So let's try an example BST:

[image]

Which could be constructed to look something like this in JavaScript:

```js
{
  left: {
    left: {
      value: 1,
    },
    value: 2,
    right: {
      value: 3,
    },
  },
  value: 4,
  right: {
    value: 5,
  },
}
```

You can [run this code in your browser's dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/javascript) by pasting in the above function (and hitting enter) and then calling it like so:

```js
inOrderHelper({
  left: {
    left: {
      value: 1,
    },
    value: 2,
    right: {
      value: 3,
    },
  },
  value: 4,
  right: {
    value: 5,
  },
})
```

The result should look something like this:

```
Entering inOrderHelper with  {left: {…}, value: 4, right: {…} }
  Root is not null, so continue
  Traversing down the left node
  Entering inOrderHelper with  {left: {…}, value: 2, right: {…}}
    Root is not null, so continue
    Traversing down the left node
    Entering inOrderHelper with  { value: 1 }
      Root is not null, so continue
      Traversing down the left node
      Entering inOrderHelper with  undefined
        Root is null, so back up
        Exiting inOrderHelper

      The root value is  1

      Traversing down the right node
      Entering inOrderHelper with  undefined
        Root is null, so back up
        Exiting inOrderHelper
      Exiting inOrderHelper

    The root value is 2

    Traversing down the right node
    Entering inOrderHelper with { value: 3 }
      Root is not null, so continue
      Traversing down the left node
      Entering inOrderHelper with  undefined
        Root is null, so back up
        Exiting inOrderHelper

      The root value is  3

      Traversing down the right node
      Entering inOrderHelper with  undefined
        Root is null, so back up
        Exiting inOrderHelper
      Exiting inOrderHelper
    Exiting inOrderHelper

  The root value is 4

  Traversing down the right node
  Entering inOrderHelper with { value: 5 }
    Root is not null, so continue
    Traversing down the left node
    Entering inOrderHelper with  undefined
      Root is null, so back up
      Exiting inOrderHelper

    The root value is 5

    Traversing down the right node
    Entering inOrderHelper with  undefined
      Root is null, so back up
      Exiting inOrderHelper
    Exiting inOrderHelper
  Exiting inOrderHelper
```

You can also use online tools, like [BinaryTreeVisualizer](http://btv.melezinek.cz/binary-search-tree.html), to see this demonstrated with animations.

> How does the program know to stop before the tree is finished? It seems to me that it should continue to go to the runner's left node until it is null, at which point it will skip the console.log

Notice that when the function recurses down the left side, when the recursive function returns, control returns to the parent function, which continues on down the right side. When a recursive function returns, it doesn't immediately end the parent function. The parent function treats the recursive function like any other function. It calls it and then, when it returns, goes on to the next thing.

> How does the program know that a node has already been printed? It seems to me that it would just print the minimum value repeatedly or once before traversing to the maximum value but apparently the nodes are being checked off somehow.

This is where javascript gets a little bit confusing. Essentially, the function is trying to go down the left and right side, but if the root value is a string, like `"B"`, then `root.left` and `root.right` refer to properties that don't exist. In javascript, rather than throwing an error, it just returns `undefined`. So when we recurse on `root.left` and that value is `undefined` then we do nothing.

So, in our example tree:

```js
{
  left: {
    left: {
      value: 1,
    },
    value: 2,
    right: {
      value: 3,
    },
  },
  value: 4,
  right: {
    value: 5,
  },
}
```

Our first root is `{ left: { ... }, value: 4, right: { value: 5 } }`

When we go to the left, root is now `{ left: { value: 1 }, value: 2, right: { value: 3 } }`.

When we go left again, the root is now `{ value: 1 }`.

When we go left again, the root is now `undefined`, so we do nothing and return to the previous call where the root is `{ value: 1 }`.

We print `1`.

Then we go to the right and the root is now `undefined`, so we do nothing and return to the previous call where the root is `{ value: 1 }`.

We're done with `{ value: 1 }`, so we return to the previous call where the root is `{ left: { value: 1 }, value: 2, right: { value: 3 } }`

We print `2`.

Now we go down to the right, and the process repeats as it did for the left, printing `3`.

We then go back up to the previous root, `{ left: { ... }, value: 4, right: { value: 5 } }`

We print `4`.

The we go to the right and, as with the previous examples, print `5`.

We return and, since we've arrived at the original function call, we return and end the program.

The end result is that we printed `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, in that order.

> How are all the values printed? For example, if the second smallest value is the right node of the third smallest, value, how is the second smallest value account for?

I'm not sure what you're asking, but it's important to note that this function does not sort the tree. It just reports the values. So if the BST was not constructed properly (e.g. a smaller value is the right of a larger value), then it will print those values out of order as well.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
1  function inOrder(root) {
2    if (!root) return;
3    inOrderHelper(root.left);
4    console.log(root.data);
5    inOrderHelper(root.right);
6  }
7
8  inOrder(root) // 2 4 6 7 9
```

**Q1**

Line 2 stops the recursion progressing forever.

At the bottom left of the graph, node 2 is evaluated, then `inOrder` is invoked with `left` as an argument, which is `undefined`. Line 2 evaluates to `true` and immediately returns. Once it has returned to the calling point, execution continues. Line 4 is evaluated, meaning `2` is printed to the console. Then line 5 is evaluated. This happens every time the algorithm hits a node without a left or a right subtree.

**Q2**

It uses the stack-based nature of the programming language itself, to keep track of where it is in the graph. Every time the function is called a new stack frame is added to the stack, and every time a function completes, that stack frame is removed.

**Q3**

Nodes are printed according to their position in the graph, not their value.

```js
const root = {
    data: 7,
    left: {
        data: 4,
        left: {
            data: 2
        },
        right: {
            data: 6
        }
    },
    right: {
        data: 9
    }
}

function inOrder(root) {
    if (!root)
        return;
    inOrder(root.left);
    console.log(root.data);
    inOrder(root.right);
}

inOrder(root)
```

Comment: Upvoted.  Note, though, that the example is not a BST.

Comment: Great explanation!  I wish I could accept multiple responses as the answer to my question because illuminating the stack-based nature of recursion was really what made the concept click in my mind after reading JDB's answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As other's have stated, using the Chrome debugger to step through this code is a great way to start to understand what is going on. I suggest also drawing your own pictures similar to what other's have shown in their answers to help you follow along with what the debugger is doing.

> How does the program know to stop before the tree is finished? It seems to me that it should continue to go to the runner's left node until it is null, at which point it will skip the console.log

The function continually visits the left node until it reaches a leaf. Then it gradually returns, prints out the data, and visits each right node. The program will terminate after it has visited every node in the tree.

> How does the program know that a node has already been printed? It seems to me that it would just print the minimum value repeatedly or once before traversing to the maximum value but apparently the nodes are being checked off somehow.

It doesn't keep track of visited nodes as you assume. It traverses as far as it can down the left side of the tree before working its way back to the root and visiting the right side along the way.

> How are all the values printed? For example, if the second smallest value is the right node of the third smallest, value, how is the second smallest value account for?

Because at each recursive call, it prints the value of the current "root".